# Continuity and inverse continuity in the homemorphism of $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ and $S^2$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In the proof of the homeomorphism between $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ and $S^2$. I am following the following approach:

Let $X=\{ [z_0:z_1] \in \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1  \; | \; z_1 \neq 0 \} $. Show that $\phi : X \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $ s.t. $[z_0:z_1] \mapsto z_0/z_1 $ is a homemorphism. Once I prove the homeormorphism, then using the stereographic projection and one-point compactification, I can show that homeomorphism between $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ and $S^2$.

My attempt: $\phi$ is surjective since, any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ can be mapped by $[z:1] \in \mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1 $.

$\phi$ is injective since, $z_0/z_1 =z_2/z_3 \Rightarrow [z_0:z_1] = [z_2:z_3] $.

Doubt: How do I show that $\phi$ is continuous map and also an open map or continuous and inverse is also continuous to show the homeomorphism?

Comment: How do you *define* $[z_0: z_1]$, and how the topology on $X$? As some quotient topology?

Comment: $[z_0:z_1] $ is the equivalence class in $\mathbb{C}^2$ where the relation is defined by $a \sim b \iff a = \lambda b $ for some $\lambda  \in \mathbb{C}$. The topology on $X$ is that of the quotient topology in the identification space just described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\phi$ is well-defined : $(z_0,z_1) \sim (z_2,z_3)$ under the equivalence relation implies $\phi([z_0,z_1]) = \phi([z_2,z_3]) = \frac{z_0}{z_1}$, so the image of $\phi$ does not depend on the representative pair. Also a map from a quotient (here $q:\Bbb C \times \Bbb C^\ast \to \Bbb{CP}^1$, sending $(z_0,z_1)$ to $[z_0,z_1]$, induces the quotient topology) is continuous iff the composition with $q$ is continuous (standard universal property for quotient maps) and here $\phi \circ q$ equals the map $(u,v) \to \frac{u}{v}$ which is continuous. ($\Bbb C$ is a topological group..). That the inverse is continuous is also clear, as the map $z \to (z,1) \in \Bbb C \times \Bbb C^\ast$ is also continuous..)